# GAE NDB Confused about Models and duplicating attributes

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to learn Google App Engine's NDB and I'm confused about the structure of models.

My situation is similar to a CMS platform with Post Types (like in WordPress), so I have "Blogs" and "Pages". All of these Post Types require the same set of attributes: Parent, Name, Slug, Template, Content, Status, and Date.

So far, I gather that I need to create a Model for these like this:

```
class Post(ndb.Expando):
    parent = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug = ndb.StringProperty()
    template = ndb.StringProperty()
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

(I'm using Expando because I will be adding "unknown" attributes in my application)

But with this structure, all of my posts (in every Post Type) will be within the same "kind", so queries will take longer (if I'm not mistaken).

- How can I create many Models (kinds) with the same attributes?
- Do I copy & paste the above Model under different class names?
- Is it possible to create new Models dynamically (similar to "Custom Post Types" in WordPress)? Does it work if I use `ndb.Key('Blog', blogid)` instead of declaring a Model?
- Do I create a Model called `class PostType(ndb.Model)` that stores the "Post Types" and give them ancestors of Posts? (If I'm not mistaken, this would cause problems because updating a Post would "lock" the entire ancestor tree for a second or so)

My primary goal is efficiency. Thanks!

### Updates:

As written by Dan and mgilson, adding sub-classes of the main Post class Model is a good way to solve this:

```
class Post(ndb.Expando):
    parent = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug = ndb.StringProperty()
    template = ndb.StringProperty()
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Blog(Post):
    pass
```

However, this requires writing the Models statically. Is there a way to accomplish this dynamically (without declaring them as Models beforehand)?

### Update:

Following the advice given below, I decided to keep all of my entities under the same `kind`. I might decide later on to change this to subclasses (separate `kind`s for each "Post Type") if my queries get messy. Thank you all for your great advice!

Comment: To pick up on just this bit "will be within the same "kind", so queries will take longer (if I'm not mistaken)." You are mistaken. The number of entities in the datastore has no effect on the time it takes to query.

Comment: The potential problem with subclassing is they different entity types, so you can't simply query for all Posts and Blog  in a single query.  You may not need this in which case it's fine.  If you do then you look at somthing like polymodels.  You can create models on the fly however you will need to start using much lower level api's to and probably metaclasses to achieve this.  At the moment your questions suggest you not be ready for this yet.  

If all the models share the same properties, why not just include a Post Type property and keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create many Models with the same attributes?

You can subclass:

```
class SpecialPost(Post):
    """Special post type that is a different kind than Post."""
```

Though it's often easy enough to use the same kind and just add an extra field that represents the kind of post which you can filter on in queries.

> Is it possible to create new Models dynamically (similar to "Custom Post Types" in WordPress)? Does it work if I use `ndb.Key('Blog', blogid)` instead of declaring a Model?

I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you're asking here.  You *can* dynamically create models the same way you can dynamically create classes in python (using `type`), but you probably don't want to be doing this.  Getting those dynamically created models (and keeping track of their names) will probably end up giving you serious headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason I don't want to use the same "kind" for all Post Types, is that querying all Posts in all Post Types sounds like bad practice. I'd rather query within the specific Post Type (where Post Type = kind). Does querying all entities vs. querying a specific kind make much of a difference in response times? Should I not worry about that?

Comment: @ThePloki -- The datastore is built to be super scalable.  As long as you have an index on the property that you're querying, there shouldn't be a huge difference in load times.  There definitely are _other_ reasons you might want to keep them separate (e.g. different kinds of posts might have different properties).

Answer (score 1):

Basically a simple example of subclassing, which @mgilson mentioned already.

```
class Post(ndb.Expando):
    parent = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug = ndb.StringProperty()
    template = ndb.StringProperty()
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Blog(Post):
    someint = ndb.IntegerProperty()

blog = Blog(status='new', someint=2)
key = blog.put()
print key.kind()
```

As for dynamically creating models, from the Model's [Constructor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Constructor) doc:

> An application won't normally call Model(), but is likely to call the
>   constructor of a class that inherits from Model. This creates a new
>   instance of this model, also known as an entity.

Even if possible (I didn't dig too deep inside `ndb/models.py` to say with certainty that it's not) it doesn't appear a clear thing. Personally I'd stay away from that and instead re-think the need for such dynamically created models.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot!